# Array key value to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Lets say there an array

```
['1','val1','2','val2']; //etc
```

I cant figure out how to turn this into a JSON format so I can call x.1 == 'val1'

```
{'1':'val1', '2':'val2'}
```

The only thing I have tried it this and it doesn't work the same and adds a weird space at the beginning of a key name

```
var newString = '{'
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i+=2){
    if(i < x.length){
        newString += JSON.stringify(x[i]) + ':' 
        newString += JSON.stringify(x[i+1]) + ',';
    } else{
        newString = newString + JSON.stringify(x[i]) + ':' + JSON.stringify(x[i+1]).replace(' ', '');
    }
}
newString += '}';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and assign the value.

```js
var array = ['1', 'val1', '2', 'val2'],
    result = {},
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) result[array[i++]] = array[i++];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `for` loop to iterate over indicies `[0 and 1]`, then `[2 and 3]`, etc, to create an array of entries, and then yo can create an object from it with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr = ['1','val1','2','val2'];
const entries = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  entries.push([arr[i], arr[i + 1]]);
}
const obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(obj);
```

Or, if you're using an old browser which doesn't support `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr = ['1','val1','2','val2'];
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  obj[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Because you want to be able to use the result as an *object*, not as a JSON string, you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify` anywhere.

Comment: Works fine here, you're probably using an older browser, but you can use bracket notation to assign to an object instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a JSON string, build an object.  And if your goal really is to have a JSON string, then stringify the resulting object.

```
var obj = {};
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i += 2) {
  obj[x[i]] = x[i + 1];
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```